# Some many to one objects missing in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

HI I have two Tables( Movie as **Movy** Entity and Producers as **Producer**). Movie has one producer and producer has many movies.here is the er diag
[Picture: ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyjbK.png)

When i set the data soure of my DataGridView to  ctx.Movies.ToList() some movie in the list doesnt have any producer. even though its not null in database. 
[Picture:Program with missing producer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeeyj.png)

```
//Movie Entity Class
 public partial class Movy
    {
        public short VideoCode { get; set; }
        public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
        public string MovieType { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }
        public Nullable<float> RentalPrice { get; set; }
        public string ProducerID { get; set; }
        public string Director { get; set; }
        public string Media { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> TotalStock { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> NumberRented { get; set; }
        public virtual Producer Producer { get; set; }
    }
}

//Producer Entity Class
 public partial class Producer
    {
        public Producer()
        {
            this.Movies = new HashSet<Movy>();
        }
        public string ProducerID { get; set; }
        public string ProducerName { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Movy> Movies { get; set; }
    }

// MyDBEntities ctx
public partial class MYDBEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MYDBEntities()
            : base("name=MYDBEntities")
        {
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Movy> Movies { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Producer> Producers { get; set; }
    }

//this is my function in windows form which is having some producer missing in movie datalist. i have added the picture of output

     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MYDBEntities ct = new MYDBEntities();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ct.Movies.ToList();
        }
```

P.S: [Picture:Database data]

```
/* i checked each product and its producer. some producer is null there.
  even though its not null in database(I have uploaded db pic) [3]*/

            List<Movy> ls =  ct.Movies.ToList();
            foreach(Movy mov in ls)
            {
                //some mov.Producer is null here. 
            }
```

Comment: What do you see if you run a `TSQL` query against the database directly? `SELECT * from [Producer] WHERE ProducerId like '%Universal%'`

Comment: It gives me the producer named universal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the problem. it is Entity Framework wasn't able to automap some string foreign key. 
for me those movie was having producerID = 'Universal' foreign key, that movies Producer Object was null(Couldn't map). so once I update my database like using following query follwoing: it working now: 
`update Movies set Producer='Warner' where Producer='Universal';`

Comment: And Universal was followed by a trailing space. Sql Query was ignoring the space. but c# wasnt. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793494/some-many-to-one-objects-missing-in-datagridview) method.

```
MYDBEntities ct = new MYDBEntities();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ct.Movies.Include("Producer").ToList();
```

Comment: Still some producer null after adding Include

Comment: Are you using Model First approach? It seem that relationship between Movie and Product uses ProducerID which is ***String*** data type instead of ***Integer*** or ***Guid***. We don't normally use ***float*** for currency and ***short*** for TotalStock  and NumberRented instead we use ***decimal*** and ***integer***. It is a bit weird.

Comment: Yea i m using model first. i have the database given already. cant change it. it is generated code

Comment: You don't have to use Model First approach. You can generate Code First POCO from existing database.

Comment: Sorry I have generated POCO from existing database.this is all generated code from existing database.and sorry for my confusion about model first. i have generated all the code from existing database.

Comment: I could not say what causes the issue without looking at your database and code. In good database design, we normally use either ***uniqueidentifier/Guid*** or ***int*** for primary key. In EF, not many of people use EDMX these days; instead we either start from Code First or generate Code First from an existing database.

Comment: thats true. if for this reason its happening then i need to talk with my lecturer. he gave me this database to do the assignment.